# Thinking Sphinx mistakenly looks for mysql instead of postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

My database.yml file and my Gemfile specify the use of postgresql.  However, when I run

```
rake ts:index
```

I get the error

```
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- mysql2
```

Why is Thinking Sphinx looking for mysql?

Comment: mysql2 gem is required for connecting to Sphinx, so please include it even  if you're using PostgreSQL as your database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mysql2 gem is required for connecting to Sphinx, so please include it even if you're using PostgreSQL as your database.

Reference:
https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx

Comment: That's not fair for developers that'd like to keep a light stack.